# ActionBar Search + Fragment + SQLite DB - Not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to add search functionality to my Listview which is backed by a Cursor Adapter. My search is inside a fragment which contains this listview. I am following a tutorial from [Here](http://www.androprogrammer.com/2014/02/add-searching-in-list-view.html). However it does not seem to be working. Previously I had implemented search on this list with a AutoComplete Edit Text and it was working fine with the below code:

```
SEARCH.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                CursorAdapter filterAdapter = (CursorAdapter) Cur;
                filterAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }
        });

        Cur.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                return dbHelper.getDirectoryList(constraint);
            }
        });
```

Now my code is as follows (Inside this particular fragment):

Class Declaration:

```
public class FragmentTab1 extends Fragment implements OnQueryTextListener{
```

My OnCreateOptionsMenu:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService( Context.SEARCH_SERVICE );
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        return true;
    }
```

My onQueryTextSubmit:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText){
        // this is your adapter that will be filtered
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)){
            lv.clearTextFilter();
        }
        else{
            lv.setFilterText(newText.toString());
        }

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

However this does not seem to be working, is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: see http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java#1865

Comment: Does not provide a clear answer though. I have already a search box implemented - which I dont want, I want to migrate the search into the Action Bar.

Comment: did you see the first "if" ?

Comment: Let me check on that